# Worklight :: Is there scheduled tasks?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

I've come to realize I would like to have a app maintenance task run on a periodical basis. 
Let's say, cleaning up the DB once per week or something like that.

On IBM BPM there is a system primitive to do that, it's a Scheduled UCA.
Does IBM Worklight have such mechanism?

In alternative, is there a better way than creating my own task in Java with `ScheduledExecutorService`?

I would like to avoid SO crons so that I don't have app logic hidden away in scattered places.

I'm using worklight 6.2 with WLP 8.5.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this approach - https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/configuring_a_polling_event_source_to_send_push_notifications?lang=en

instead of sending notifications just do whatever you need to